# Why is Safari on IPhone XS Max applying phone linking to values inside data attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

We have a html/javascript widget that our clients can add to their sites webpages by adding a  tag in the head of the page, and adding an element in the body the page.

```
<a href="#" class="ourwidgetclass" data-product-id="1234567890" />
```

When the page loads, our javascript finds all the elements on that page with that class, grabs the productId from that data attribute, does a webservice call to our API and renders a little product visualisation for the supplied product Id.

Yesterday we received a bug report that this html is rendering as follows

```
<a href="#" class="ourwidgetclass" data-product-id="<a href="tel:1234567890">1234567890</a>" />
```

This is:

- localised to safari on iOS
- only occuring on the IPhone XS Max - it's not occuring on any other iphone device

I've looked around on SO and the usual recommendation of adding the following meta tag isn't an option for us as we can (or shouldn't) modify the meta tags on the site of teh client that's rendering our widget. ( `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` )

So aside from writing some horrid javascript/regex to try and identifiy when safari cocks up our data like this... has anyone got any ideas why this might be happening in such a localized fashion.

Comment: Not sure if this is intended, but `<a>` tags need a closing `</a>` that might be the cause? Also, you can try to prefix your product id with a letter or two and strip those letters when you process the request if fixing the markup doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: on the `<a>` tag comment, I went back and checked the real code, it has a closing `</a>` alright so not that. Unfrotunately not much we can do about the product code as that's being injected by the clients CMs/Site so we have to support whatever strings they pass. We have a workaround but I'm more interested in getting to the root cause of this issue.